# Will the IRS automatically pay me back if I paid them too much?

Tags: united-states, irs, income-tax-refund

After the 2015 tax season, the IRS sent me a bill for my 2014 tax (because I made an amendment), which I paid immediately.

A few days later, a check from the IRS for my 2015 arrived, which I deposited.

Finally, an IRS letter arrived explaining that they already deduced the amount I owed on my 2014 tax from my 2015 refund check, meaning that I shouldn't have paid the 2014 bill.

Given that I did, would they notice and refund me that amount or do I need to contact them and ask for it?

Comment: Did the letter mention that you overpaid, or did they not realize that you sent a check based on the first letter?

Comment: They did not realize that I sent a check for my 2014 tax.

Comment: To be clear, you mean during the _filing season_ this spring (2016) after you filed (and they processed) your return for 2015? If you indicated on the check or payment voucher it was for 2014 and they posted it to 2014 in addition to the offset, that 'module' now shows overpaid and they will refund it -- but probably not very fast. IRS still does a _lot_ of their processing on 1970s-style batch systems and it may take _a month or two_. If you don't hear by then, call 800-829-1040 and check your account status.

Answer (score 2):

If they know/agree that they owe you money, they *will* send it to you, unless you explicitly told them to apply it to next year's taxes.

Comment: How can you be so sure that they *will* send a refund?

Comment: Because that's what they do. They really have no interest in keeping money they aren't legally entitled to. The IRS is annoying, and not always efficient, but they really are essentially honest and as trustworthy as any large organization can be. The base assumption really can be that if they agree they owe you money, they will send you the money -- my audit resulted in a large refund check after I submitted the corrected paperwork. (I'd forgotten to claim a large pile of investment losses; they caught it for me.) If you do your part, they will do theirs.

Comment: I understand, but it's the "not always efficient" side of the IRS that makes me hesitate to be certain that the check is already in the mail.

Comment: If you think it got lost somewhere, write or phone. Never hurts to check.

Comment: The problem is they may not realize that they owe me money. In the letter, they said that you owe us 2014 tax, but it's OK you don't have to pay us because we deduct it from your 2015 refund. They may not know that I already paid the 2014 amount I owed before I got that explanation.

Comment: I said: If they know. If you aren't sure they know, or aren't sure you know, contact them, just as you would any other organization, company, or individual. That seemed too obvious to be a question...?

Comment: (Of course  @heusenberg expressing uncertainty is entirely appropriate... ;-)